# Encounter the RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, autograd

I'm getting the following error when calling .backward():

Encounter the RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Here's the code:

```
for i, j, k in zip(X, Y, Z):
    A[:, i, j] = A[:, i, j] + k
```

I've tried .clone(), torch.add(), and so on.

Please help!

Comment: What are `X`, `Y`, and `Z`? Are they lists of numbers or tensors? Are they a result of operations involving parameters?

Comment: X and Y are leaf tensors. Z is a non-leaf tensor resulting from the previous layer.

Comment: Good, are there any repeated indices in X,Y? (e.g. does the pair (1,1) show up two or more times?)

Comment: Yes, that's why I need to sum them up. Ex: (3, 9, 0.5), (3, 9, 0.4) should result in (3, 9, 0.9)

Comment: A.shape: ([32, 300, 300]), X.shape, Y.shape: ([32, 200]) and Z.shape : ([32, 200, 1]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments I'm a bit confused about what you want to accomplish. The code you gave gives me an error using the dimensions you provided in the comments

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    A[:, i, j] = A[:, i, j] + k
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (32) must match the size of tensor b (200) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

But here's what I think you want to do, please correct me in the comments if this is wrong...

Given tensors `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, each entry of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` correspond to a coordinate (x,y) and a value z. What you want is to add z to `A` at coordinate (x,y). For most cases the batch dimension is kept independent, although its not clear that's the case in the code you posted. For now that's what I'll assume you want to do.

For example lets say `A` contains all zeros and has shape 3x4x5 and `X`,`Y` are shape 3x3 and `Z` is shape 3x3x1. For this example let's assume `A` contains all zeros to start, and `X`, `Y`, and `Z` have the following values

```
X = tensor([[1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3],                                
            [2, 2, 2]])                               
Y = tensor([[1, 2, 3],                                
            [1, 2, 3],                                                        
            [1, 1, 1]])             
Z = tensor([[[0.1], [0.2], [0.3]],
            [[0.4], [0.5], [0.6]],
            [[0.7], [0.8], [0.9]]])
```

Then we would expect `A` to have the following values after the operation

```
A = tensor([[[0,   0,   0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                          
             [0,   0.1, 0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                      
             [0,   0,   0.2, 0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                      
             [0,   0,   0,   0.3, 0]],                                                                                                                                                                   

            [[0,   0,   0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                      
             [0,   0.4, 0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                      
             [0,   0,   0.5, 0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                      
             [0,   0,   0,   0.6, 0]],                                                                                                                                                                   

            [[0,   0,   0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                    
             [0,   0,   0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                    
             [0,   2.4, 0,   0,   0],                                                                                                                                                                    
             [0,   0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

In order to accomplish this we can make use to the [`index_add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add) function which allows us to add to a list of indices. Since this only supports 1-dimensional operations we first need to convert `X`,`Y` to a linear index for flattened tensor `A`. Afterwards we can un-flatten to the original shape.

```
layer_size = A.shape[1] * A.shape[2]                                                                                                                                                                       
index_offset = torch.arange(0, A.shape[0] * layer_size, layer_size).unsqueeze(1)                                                                                                                           
indices = (X * A.shape[2] + Y) + index_offset                                                                                                                                                              
A = A.view(-1).index_add(0, indices.view(-1), Z.view(-1)).view(A.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact the pairs are not unique, that's why I need to sum them up. Ex: (3, 9, 0.5), (3, 9, 0.4) should result in (3, 9, 0.9)

Comment: @natasha_667 I updated the answer with a solution which will work for the non-unique case as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried here and got an error regarding the dimensions. I'll be sincere, I don't understand your solution yet! Here are the actual dimensions: A.shape: ([32, 300, 300]), X.shape, Y.shape: ([32, 200]) and Z.shape : ([32, 200, 1]).

Comment: I see, i was worried that there may be a batch dimension on X and Y. I'll need to update this again. Third times a charm!

Comment: @natasha_667 I've updated the answer, let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot!

Comment: @natasha_667 I'm glad to hear! If this answers your question please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Sure! How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: BTW, I've posted another question, please help me if you can ;)